# osx audio unit multi channel output

Tags: macos, core-audio, openframeworks

i have been searching the net for an answer for weeks without luck.

i have a maudio profire 610 multi channel audio interface.
how do i set the AudioStreamBasicDescription properly to work with all 8 output channels?
currently it only works with the first 2 channels.

```
    UInt32 busCount = 3; //numberOfOutputBusses;
AudioStreamBasicDescription outputASBD2 = {
    .mSampleRate       = 44100,
    .mFormatID         = kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    .mFormatFlags      = kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical, 
    .mChannelsPerFrame = busCount,
    .mFramesPerPacket  = 1,
    .mBitsPerChannel   = sizeof(Float32) * 8,
    .mBytesPerPacket   = sizeof(Float32) * busCount,
    .mBytesPerFrame    = sizeof(Float32) * busCount
};

AudioUnitSetProperty(*_unit,
                                    kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                    kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                    1,
                                    &outputASBD2,
                                    sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription);
```

i am working of the ofxaudiounit addon for openframeworks:
https://github.com/antimodular/ofxAudioUnit

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
     UInt32 propertySize;
  Boolean writable = false;
  OSStatus status = AudioUnitGetPropertyInfo(*_unit,
                                             kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap,
                                             kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                             0,
                                             &propertySize, &writable);
  //SignalIf_(writable == false);
  cout<<"writable "<<&writable<<endl;

  long nChannels = propertySize / sizeof(SInt32);
  long* channelMapPtr = (long*)malloc(propertySize);

  cout<<"nChannels "<<nChannels<<endl;

  UInt32 scratch = propertySize;
  status = AudioUnitGetProperty(*_unit,
                                  kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap,
                                  kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                  0,
                                  channelMapPtr,
                                  &scratch);

  //  channelMapPtr[0] = 0;
  for (long i = 0; i < nChannels; i++)
  {
      channelMapPtr[i] = -1;
  }

 channelMapPtr[3] = 0;
 channelMapPtr[5] = 1;

  OFXAU_RET_BOOL(AudioUnitSetProperty(*_unit,
                                        kAudioOutputUnitProperty_ChannelMap,
                                        kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                                        0,
                                        channelMapPtr,
                                        scratch),"setting output unit's device ID");

  free((void *)channelMapPtr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Canonical format is noninterleaved, so each buffer only has one channel so `.mBytesPerPacket` and `.mBytesPerFrame` should be `sizeof(Float32)`. Then you need to create multiple (`busCount`) buffers to pass into the AudioUnit with something like

```
AudioBufferList *bufferList = (AudioBufferList*)malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + (sizeof(AudioBuffer) * (busCount - 1)));
bufferList->mNumberBuffers = busCount;
for ( int i=0; i < bufferList->mNumberBuffers; i++ ) {
    bufferList->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels = 1;
    bufferList->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(float);
    bufferList->mBuffers[i].mData = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE * sizeof(float));
}
```

Comment: thanks. i will give this a try.

meanwhile would this approache have to change if i use any of these other formatflags?


kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger
kAudioFormatFlagsNativeEndian
kAudioFormatFlagIsNonMixable 

i don't really know what they stand for.

thanks again.

Comment: kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical includes NativeEndian. Yes, it would change if you used SignedInteger because SignedInteger seems to put everything into one buffer. I don't know what IsNonMixable is for :)